# Should I be using BUILKIO to output Vita49 packets from a REDHAWK device?

Tags: redhawksdr

I feel like I am missing something, all of the VITA49 examples seem to be using TCP or UDP.

Is there a specification or standard way of providing VITA49 packets for consumption?

Should I be performing the conversion and providing standard complex samples with Keywords?

I have looked at the rh.vita49 loopback demo waveform, and the MSDD device source, as well as the sourceVITA49 and sinkVITA49 component.  All of these use either a tcp or udp packet stream.

If the standard is to use sockets to pass VITA49 packets, then where should I be looking to understand how to construct a device that adheres to the standard?

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER

I was able to talk to an experienced REDHAWK developer.

There is no standard, per-se, with that said the approach I took was to make use of the socket.sourceVita49 asset.  This asset consumes the Vita49 packets and inserts appropriate keywords etc based upon context packet.  This required me update my device to support setting the hardware up to send Vita49 via TCP.  This actually provided an easier solution for me, as I wasn't having to bust the VRT apart.

### Examples:

The best example I found of consuming Vita49 was the MSDD device asset.

---

### NOTE:

After reviewing the MSDD, it does not look to be too difficult to create a device that consumes VITA49 VRL,VRT packets and produce time stamped samples.  I will be investigating that in the future.